# Billboards InterviewStreet - Code Optimization

Tags: c#, optimization, algorithm

Heres the link to the original question . [Billboards Link](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4f2c2e3780aeb)

I initially declared n*k array which led to a `Out Of Memory Exception`.

Then I resorted to using just 2 * k matrix and alternating between 0 and 1 during each iteration. Now the issue is time limit. As of now 8/10 cases are solved using this approach.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Billboards
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long n, k;
        string line;
        string[] parts = new string[2];
        line = Console.ReadLine();
        parts = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        n = long.Parse(parts[0]);
        k = long.Parse(parts[1]);
        long i, j;
        long[]  c = new long[n];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            c[i] = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        long[][] dp = new long[2][];
        long max = 0;
        int var1, var2, temp;
        var1 = 0;
        var2 = 1;
        for(i=0;i<=1;i++){
            dp[i] = new long[k + 1];
        }

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            dp[var2][0] = max;
    max = 0;
            for (j = 1; j <= k; j++)
            {
                dp[var2][j] = Math.Max(dp[var1][j - 1] + c[i-1], dp[var1][j]);
        if(dp[var2][j] > max)
        max = dp[var2][j];                     
            }
    temp = var1;
    var1 = var2;
    var2 = temp;
        }            

        max = Max(dp[var1]);              

        Console.WriteLine(max);
    }

    static long Max(long[] arr)
    {
        long max = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > max)
            {
                max = arr[i];
            }                
        }
        return max;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are on a code review forum I would suggest you to give more meaningful names to variables, avoid redundant assignments (e.g. initial array assigned to `parts` variable is not used), and split the logic into smaller methods that perform distinct functionality. Also you can use `Max(IEnumerable<long>)` extension method instead of writing your own.

But I guess that's not what you want to hear, so in terms of algorithms I suggest you to apply the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) to this problem instead of full search. If you find it difficult to understand and implement, I would recommend you to pass the [Machine Learning course](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml) from Coursera or [Introduction to Artificial Intelligence](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs271/CourseRev/1) from Udacity

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But I am sure there is a DP solution to this problem. Will try that approach too.

Comment: According to constraints N<=10^5, K<=N. So in worst case you have a nested loop with 10^10 iterations, and that is the reason why your solution timed out.

Comment: Yep ..Need to get a better algorithm..

Comment: A* explores most promising paths first, so you can find a solution with just slightly more than N iterations